# Tipsy HTML isn't working every time

Tags: jquery, html, tipsy

I have the exact same piece of script triggering Tipsy on 2 pages in my site, and one is showing it right, but the other isn't

TIPSY CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tipsy-trigger').tipsy({gravity: 'n', html: true});
    });
</script>
```

CODE THAT WORKS: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3cpw11fz0iwzzf/works.jpg)

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o tipsy-trigger" original-title="Added by System Account<br/>12th September 2013 11:53am<br/><hr/>Edited by System Account<br/>18th November 2013 11:57am"></i>
```

SAME CODE ON ANOTHER PAGE THAT WON'T: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/nv9dumjia1ajlb7/doesnt.jpg)

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o tipsy-trigger" original-title="Added by Paul Rowe<br/>27th September 2013 12:09pm<br/><hr>Edited by System Account<br/>19th November 2013 2:15pm"></i>
```

I can't find anything else differen't on the pages, and I don't get any errors in my javascript console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open original [tipsy.js](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/blob/master/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js#L194) & change `html : true` for some reason(can be solved) your custom option is not getting loaded in tipsy.